# ES6 import module with Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-babel

I am trying to import my ES6 module into a file and running Gulp to concat and minify the file. I'm running into a **ReferenceError: require is not defined at all.js(transpiled) line no 3**. 
I have transpiled the code using gulp-babel.

My js files are:

**cart.js:**

```
class Cart{
  constructor(){
    this.cart = [];
    this.items = items = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Dove Soap',
        price: 39.99
    },{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Axe Deo',
        price: 99.99
    }];
  }


  getItems(){
    return this.items;
  }


}

export {Cart};
```

**app.js:**

```
import {Cart} from 'cart.js';

let cart = new Cart();

console.log(cart.getItems());
```

**gulpfile.js:**

```
"use strict";

let gulp = require('gulp');
let jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
let concat = require('gulp-concat');
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
let rename = require('gulp-rename');
let babel = require('gulp-babel');


// Lint Task
gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});


// Concatenate & Minify JS
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('js/*.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['env']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify().on('error', function(e){
          console.dir(e);
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['lint','scripts']);
```

**app.js(transpiled):**

```
'use strict';

var _cart = require('cart.js'); //Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

var cart = new _cart.Cart();

console.log(cart.getItems());
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Cart = function () {
  function Cart() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Cart);

    this.cart = [];
    this.items = items = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Dove Soap',
      price: 39.99
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Axe Deo',
      price: 99.99
    }];
  }

  _createClass(Cart, [{
    key: 'getItems',
    value: function getItems() {
      return this.items;
    }
  }]);

  return Cart;
}();

exports.Cart = Cart;
```

Comment: I am trying to run app.js in the browser, so if I am correct require('something') won't work. Do i need to browserify?

Comment: You need to run webpack-stream after babel. It's not very fun to install and I gave up trying to create an example. gulp-webpack is another package, but I don't think it's maintained anymore.

Comment: FYI, `browserify` works with `gulp` only after being wrapped properly. Here's [a recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-transforms.md) for a basic example of usage.

Comment: Could you post your final configuration with webpack/browserify? I‘m struggling with setting them up in my project and I have a similar gulp conf to yours.

Answer (score 24):

[Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) is a good bundler for handling ES6 modules. It has native ES6 module support built in so it doesn't need to use Babel unlike Browserify.

Here is a Gulp 4 config that uses Rollup:

```js
// gulp.js file in the root folder

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var rollup = require('@rollup/stream');

// *Optional* Depends on what JS features you want vs what browsers you need to support
// *Not needed* for basic ES6 module import syntax support
var babel = require('@rollup/plugin-babel');

// Add support for require() syntax
var commonjs = require('@rollup/plugin-commonjs');

// Add support for importing from node_modules folder like import x from 'module-name'
var nodeResolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve');

// Cache needs to be initialized outside of the Gulp task 
var cache;

gulp.task('js', function() {
  return rollup({
      // Point to the entry file
      input: './app.js',

      // Apply plugins
      plugins: [babel(), commonjs(), nodeResolve()],

      // Use cache for better performance
      cache: cache,

      // Note: these options are placed at the root level in older versions of Rollup
      output: {

        // Output bundle is intended for use in browsers
        // (iife = "Immediately Invoked Function Expression")
        format: 'iife',

        // Show source code when debugging in browser
        sourcemap: true

      }
    })
    .on('bundle', function(bundle) {
      // Update cache data after every bundle is created
      cache = bundle;
    })
    // Name of the output file.
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())

    // The use of sourcemaps here might not be necessary, 
    // Gulp 4 has some native sourcemap support built in
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
 
    // Where to send the output file
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js'));
});
 
gulp.task('js:watch', function(done){
  gulp.watch(['./source/**/*.js'], gulp.series('js'));
  done();
})
 
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js', 'js:watch'));
```

Comment: I thought I found a solution here, but i get a few different errors https://github.com/rollup/plugins/issues/485

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '@rollup/stream' . But Rollup is set up as a dev dependency.

Comment: npm install @rollup/stream

Answer (score 23):

You would need a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) in order to use ES6 imports. Babel is only capable of compiling ES6 code to ES5 (native JS).

Both Webpack and Browserify have made recipes for gulp:

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/integrations/#gulp
- https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/master/docs/recipes

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was never able to make Browserify work with Gulp. Webpack however worked on the first try! Thanks for saving hours of my life.

Answer (score 6):

If the above solutions don't work for you, try [**gulp-include**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-include).

> It uses directives similar to sprockets or snockets. A directive is a comment in your files that gulp-include recognizes as a command.

### Usage

*gulpfile.js:*

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const include = require('gulp-include')
 
exports.scripts = function (done) {
  gulp.src('source/js/entry.js')
    .pipe(include())
      .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
}
```

*app.js:*

```
//=require ./js/cart.js
//=include ./js/cart.js
```

Comment: That is what I really wanted!