# Unexpected Token when trying to minimize code using Uglify

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

I am running the following gulp task:

```
   var gulp = require('gulp');
   var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
   var rename = require('gulp-rename');

    gulp.task('uglify', function(){
         gulp.src('htdocs/js/*.js')
             .pipe(uglify())
             .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
             .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });
```

When I do so I get the following error:

```
GulpUglifyError: unable to minify JavaScript
Caused by: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc «{», expected: punc «;»
```

It is failing on the first line of the first JavaScript file. The line it objects to is:

```
import {removeScoreButtons} from './display.js';
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632435/es6-import-module-with-gulp

Comment: Thanks @YongQuan. I am not using `gulp-babel` so do not see how this helps. Please can you explain how the questions are related in more detail.

Comment: Look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/terser , gulp-uglify doesn't support es6, terser does.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and for your answer @pako. I was not aware that `gulp-uglify` was ES5 only. I am working in TypeScript so I will ask that to target ES5 instead.

Comment: @Mark I just took a look at `Terser`, seems to be very feature rich so tempted to use that instead. Many thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have code in ES6 you have to transpile it to ES5 with `gulp-babel` before uglify. Something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('uglify', function(){
     gulp.src('htdocs/js/*.js')
         .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env']
         }))
         .pipe(uglify())
         .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Here you have more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel