# gulp concatenate multiple js files but dependency path cause error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I am using Nodejs- v12.9.0 & gulp-4.0.2

I am concatenating all my js files from root & src directory in to a single file dist/src/allJs.js.

**Problem**: the dependent modules are not being resolved. My app.js file is at root level & log.js file is under the /src dir.

- Src

  - log.js
  - abc.js
- app.js
- main.js

app.js file has this statement 'var log = require('./src/log');'

Gulp does concatenate & minify without error but when i run my 'allJs.js' file it gives me below error.
**Error**: Cannot find module './src/log'

**My gulp task:**

```
function copyOtherJs(){
    return src(['src/*.js', 'app.js', 'main.js'], { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(concat('allJs.js'))
        .pipe(terser())
        .pipe(dest('dist/src'));
}
```

Comment: https://nshki.com/es6-in-gulp-projects/ I hope this will help you. @sanjesh

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rollup' of undefined, i tried "gulp-better-rollup": "^4.0.0" & 4.0.1 it gives error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'rollup' of undefined. Before concat() i am using this: .pipe(rollup({ plugins: [ resolve(), commonjs()] }, 'umd'))

Comment: @saifudeen, it did not help.........am i missing something ? did you encounter into the same issue and resolve & refer the same ?

Comment: Could you please check this solution?  also, did you install all packages (import)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47632435/es6-import-module-with-gulp